# when i want to insert data into mysql using JdbcOdbc Bridge driver, i get no database selected error,

Tags: mysql, jdbc, sqlexception, jdbc-odbc

i have created dsn correctly and have clear and simple code but i end up getting this error. the table structure is same as the program

```
   import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    public class Insert {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc");
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:mysqldsn","root","filimon");
                Statement st=con.createStatement();
                int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into emp values(3,'cat')");
                if (i>=1) {
                    System.out.println("inserted successfully");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("failed");
                }
                st.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

I get java.sql.SQLException: [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver][mysqld-5.7.13-log]No database selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error said that you haven't selected a database. But selection of the database would be somewhere in the ODBC configuration.

So you can do two things : Either you  fix your ODBC configuration to select a database, or (a better option) you can stop using ODBC and use the MySQL JDBC driver.

Comment: thanks alot, i fix it

Comment: welcome,any time.

Answer (score 0):

use below drivers

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname","uname","passwd");
```

---

if you still using ODBC show me your DSN configuration.

Comment: Thank you guys, I found the error in the odbc configuration